# In opencart, a SELECT query gives an empty result when record is present in table

Tags: php, mysql, csv, opencart2.x

I read a CSV file using PHP "fgetcsv" function and add/update products from the csv to my opencart store. For that I have to check whether the product exists or not.

I have written the following function for checking if a product exists in my model:

```
function existProduct($searchValue)
{       
    $sql ="SELECT `product_id` FROM ".DB_PREFIX."product WHERE `model`='".$searchValue."'"; 

    $result2 = $this->db->query($sql);

    if ($result2->num_rows > 0)
    {
        return $result2->row['product_id'];
    }

    return false;
}
```

and call the controller in the following way:

```
$productID = $this->model_tool_cust_import->existProduct($searchValue);
```

It returns an empty result when a product is present in the product table but if I pass a string value *in single quotes* it works, for example `'YS16034137'`:

```
 $productID = $this->model_tool_cust_import->existProduct('YS16034137');
```

I tried to use `trim` but it did not work.

When using `var_dump($searchValue)` I got this output:

```
string 'Y�S�1�6�0�3�4�1�3�7' (length=19)
```

Also when I trying to `echo $searchValue ;` it I got the output `YS16034137`.

Comment: From your question it is not clear what your code is *supposed to do*. You mostly describe *what does not work*. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - Consider editing your question to emphasize the expected behavior.

Comment: what is your table name ?? is  `.DB_PREFIX` intentional or it is only `DB_PREFIX` ? dot before DB_PREFIX.

Comment: DB_PREFIX get prefix in open cart  ,table name is oc_product . echo $ql  I got the output  " SELECT product_id FROM oc_product WHERE `model`='YS16034137' "

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for it   when I read column value from csv it add ***“null character” (\0)***  between each character in string. I don`t know where it comes from but I  remove null character from string using  ***str_replace("\0", "",$value)***  then it works for me thanks.